# DirectX: Calculate Gradient in the shader code

Tags: graphics, sample, directx-11, pixel-shader

I am using a pixel shader code that uses the `Sample` Function. I want to use `SampleGrad` and hence want to calculate the derivatives in my shader code. Is there a way to do the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an intrinsic function `ddx` and `ddy` to do the same. Thanks.